# reading a key from keyboard while the process is running

Tags: perl, keyboard, stdin

I wrote a simple script to manage the download time ( start and finish ) with **wget** in Linux-Gnu with **Perl**. There is no problem and everything works good, except I wish **I could read a key from keyboard when the process is running**.
I show a simple movement animation on the screen that I do not want to stop it and then read the key.

for example like **mplayer** or **mpv** that when you run it on the comman-line, you can press `q` to exit or `s` to take a picture from the screen.

A part of the script:

```
do {
    system( "clear" );
    ($h, $m, $s) = k5mt::second_to_clock(  $till_shutdown );

    set_screen();
    set_screen( 24 );

    set_screen();
    say "download was started ...";

    set_screen();
    set_screen( 24 );

    set_screen();
    printf "till finish:    %02d %02d %02d\n", $h, $m, $s;

    set_screen();
    set_screen( 24 );

    set_screen();
    say "wget pid: [$wget_pid]";

    set_screen();
    set_screen( 24 );

    set_screen();
    $waiting_temp .= $animation[ $counter_animation++ ];
    say $waiting_temp;
    if( length( $waiting ) == $counter_animation ){
        $waiting_temp = "";
        $counter_animation = 0;
    }

    set_screen();
    set_screen( 24 );

    sleep 1;
    $till_shutdown--;

} while( $till_shutdown );
```

[image]

the words **waiting till finish.....** is shown consecutively ( without interruption ) and I want to read a key like `q` to exit from the program.

**UPDATE**

I am looking for a solution with as many option as I want, if I have wanted just for exit from the program I simply tell the user to press `Ctrl + C`

Is it possible with scripting in Perl? or not? If it is, How?

> NOTE: if it is possible without any modules please say the solution
>   without any module, and if not, okay no problem

However, thank you so much.

Comment: One solution that I see is creating a sub process and do the main task while parent will keep looking for a input if user enters q then parent will kill the sub proccess

Comment: @PrashantPokhriyal Your meaning is I use `fork()` for the reading `key` ?

Comment: Yes Create a fork

Comment: @PrashantPokhriyal It is worth to examine, thank :)

Comment: Have you tried to use Term::ReadLine ? [doc](http://perldoc.perl.org/Term/ReadLine.html)

Comment: @carlosn NO. How can it help me?

Comment: @k-five as you are doing a loop to print some info, you could also check for some user input each time your loop start

Comment: @carlosn No, my friend I cannot, because `STDIN` will stop my simple animation to show on the screen

Comment: You can use [Term::ReadLine](https://metacpan.org/pod/Term::ReadLine)
 to *check* whether there is any input, and just continue if not.

Comment: you might consider using an event-loop like https://metacpan.org/release/AnyEvent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work for you

```
use 5.010;
use strict;
use Term::ReadKey;

ReadMode 4; # It will turn off controls keys (eg. Ctrl+c)

my $key; 

# It will create a child so from here two processes will run.
# So for parent process fork() will return child process id
# And for child process fork() will return 0 id

my $pid = fork(); 

# This if block will execute by the child process and not by 
# parent because for child $pid is 0     

if(not $pid){

   while(1){

        # Do your main task here
        say "hi I'm sub process and contains the main task";
        sleep 2;
    }
}

# Parent will skip if block and will follow the following code
while (1) {

   $key = ReadKey(-1); # ReadKey(-1) will perform a non-blocked read

   if($key eq 'q'){    # if key pressed is 'q'

      `kill -9 $pid`;   # then if will run shell command kill and kill
                        # the child process
       ReadMode 0;      # Restore original settings for tty.

       exit;            # Finally exit from script

    } elsif( $key eq 'h' ) {

         say "Hey! you pressed $key key for help";
    } elsif( $key ne '' ) {

        say "Hey! You pressed $key";
    }
}
```

---

References:

- [Term::ReadKey](https://metacpan.org/pod/Term::ReadKey)
- [Fork in Perl](https://perlmaven.com/fork)

Comment: I have doubt that it can manage more than `one key` or not. And I see it cannot mange more than one key in the second while(1), Am I right or not?

Comment: Yes you are right I gave only one option i.e, 'q'. You can provide as many option as you want in the if block

Comment: It works but It cannot handle more than one key. I added `h` key for show the help, and after that **no keys works**, thanks anyway

Comment: @k-five You mean to say you want additional support for help by pressing h key and q key to quit. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, I can simply tell the user to press `Ctrrl + C` if I just would want only one key or exit from the program. I looking for solution with any key.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133668/discussion-between-prashant-pokhriyal-and-k-five).

Comment: This works fine, with the following changes:

1) in Windows, you have to replace the 'kill' command with the [kill keyword](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/kill.html). It's not a bad idea on Linux or OSX, either:  `kill -9, $pid;`

2) Don't do `ReadKey(-1)`, do `ReadKey(0)` (blocking read) instead, or else that child process will be very actively busy waiting.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your program has a central loop, or if you can simply fit keyboard checks into the processing, you are better off using [`Term::ReadKey`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Term::ReadKey) than trying to fit in `fork` and handling the necessary inter-process communication

Calling `ReadKey(-1)` will do a non-blocking read, which will return a single character if a key has been hit, or `undef` otherwise. (You may supply a second parameter which is the IO channel to be used, but it will default to STDIN.)

I suggest you run this example. I have used `sleep 1` as a dummy for your loop processing

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

use Term::ReadKey;

my $n;

while () {

    my $key = ReadKey(-1);

    say "key $key entered" if defined $key;

    sleep 1;

    say ++$n;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are not worried about a little delay, you can play with `select` and `alarm` to try to handle user input.

Using select you can handle the `STDIN` and using `alarm` you can wait for a few seconds or less for user input.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl 

use common::sense;

use IO::Select;

my $sel = IO::Select->new();
$sel->add( \*STDIN );

$|++;

my $running = 1;

while ($running) {

    eval {

        local $SIG{ALRM} = sub { die 'Time Out'; };

        alarm 0.5;

        if ( $sel->can_read(0) ) {

            my $input = <STDIN>;

            chomp $input;

            print "STDIN > $input\n";

            $running = 0;

        }
    };

    if ( !$@ ) {

        select( undef, undef, undef, 0.5 );

        print ".";

    }
}

print "\nEnd Of Script\n";
```

I told you to try to use Term::ReadKey :-)

Here we go:

```
!/usr/bin/env perl 

use common::sense;
use Term::ReadKey;

my $running = 1;
my $key;

while ($running) {
    ReadMode 4;    # Turn off controls keys
    while ( not defined( $key = ReadKey(-1) ) ) {

        select( undef, undef, undef, 0.5 );

        print '.';

    }
    print "\nSTDIN> $key\n";
    ReadMode 0;  

}

print "\nEnd Of Script\n";
```

Now you just have to handle signals like quit or int to exit the loop, but using this you can capture the input and do whatever you want.

Comment: Of course I am WORRIED, this is not a good solution, thanks though for attempting

Comment: here is your comment: **Have you tried to use Term::ReadLine** you told to use **Readline**